# dhcp option domain-name-servers format

Tags: isc-dhcpd

I am dealing with subject at school and would like to check correct answer to some test question I have not passed.

What does mean a following line in config file *dhcpd.conf*?

```
option domain-name-servers ok.dm.org;
```

1. client of the DHCP server will get in the configuration: name server
   specified by IP address appropriate to ok.dm.org
2. none of the previous answers

*Other answers are 100% incorrect so I do not show them.*

The linux documentation says:

> option domain-name-servers ip-address [, ip-address... ];
>
> The domain-name-servers option specifies a list of Domain Name System (STD
>   13, RFC 1035) name servers available to the client. Servers should be
>   listed in order of preference.

Does it mean that it is not allowed to put parameter `ok.dm.org` (answer 1. is incorrect) or I can provide `ok.dm.org` and the DHCP server will somehow determine IP address from given parameter (answer 1. is correct)?

Thank you all.

Comment: It is customary to discuss the test with the professor. They are there and paid for that. Better than asking random people in the Internet. It would be better because you are showing too many doubts about this subject in a simple question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am forced to get information by myself. The teacher will not talk about the test despite of many asks. But thats out of this topic.

Comment: I will get in a time machine to 1998 and invent Google for you, ok? Wait 5 minutes and then type `option domain-name-servers ` in google.com

Comment: The client will get the IP that the hostname provided resolves to

Comment: recommend reading https://www.amazon.com/001-Illustrated-Protocols-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469 (there is the 2nd edition, the 1st  is more intelligible  and smaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHCP server seems to translate the name to an IP, as explained in this other question: https://serverfault.com/questions/518133/why-use-fqdn-as-dns-server-option-in-dhcp